# Setting the weights on the Knn classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am new to python (I am using python 3) and would like to set my weights in the knn classifier. Actually, I want to use as weight the inverse square of the distance. How can I set this index in the training matrix if this distance depends on the input you want to predict?

From what I read, I tried to create a function as a parameter, but I have some doubts when determining the inputs. My gut feeling tells me that the input of my function should be an array, more specifically, a row of my test matrix.

My `X_train` has 4 columns (so my `X_test` too)

```py
def my_weight_function(row_vector):
    w=[]
    for i in range(len(X_train)):
        dif = np.asarray(X_train[i:i+1]) - np.asarray(row_vector)
        dist = np.linalg.norm(dif)
        w.append([1/dist])
    return w
```

This functions is working

```py
my_weight_function(X_test[1:2])[0:6]
```

Now I train

```py
knn2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, weights=my_weight_function)
knn2.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

So far there are no errors, but when I do this

```py
fruit_prediction = knn2.predict([[9.2,9.6,362,0.74]])
print(fruit_prediction)
```

I have the following error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,4)
>   (1,5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is already implemented in Sklearn. All you have to do is `weights='distance'`

**From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier):**

> ‘distance’ : weight points by the inverse of their distance. in this
>   case, closer neighbors of a query point will have a greater influence
>   than neighbors which are further away.

Here is the piece of code, which implements weights as inverse of distance.

If you want to customize your weighing function using some other strategy, then your `udf` has take the distances array and then compute the weights.

> [callable] : a user-defined function which accepts an array of
>   distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the
>   weights.